# ActionMode is not working for custom actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

In my app I have AutoCompleteTextView on actionbar.The requirement is that  On long press it should show selection and copy/paste actionmode like chrome
[image]

I have tried setting setTextIsSelectable to true also but its not showing that.

Next I have tried overriding onLongClickListener and showing custom Actionmode. 
Now actionmode is showing but its overlapping actionbar. I have tried to set windowActionModeOverlay to false also. but it still overlapping.